# Flexbox menu items collapse into each other on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, menu, flexbox

http://fleurine.syberenvanmunster.com/blog/

Made a responsive menu based on flexbox and it works fine on my computer, however on iPad the menu items all collapse into each other on the right side of the screen. I can't seem to figure out what the issue is, any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL57J.png)

Answer (score 0):

its because the `position` of your nav is `absolute` , and it gets the width of the closest parent element that has the `position:relative`

add this to your css :

```
header {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't appear to make a difference

Comment: yeah , but it looks fine in my ipad , can you upload a screen shot of the problem?

Comment: Good idea, see screenshot in description. Thanks for your help